# How to validate NEW domain extensions in PHP?

Tags: php, validation, dns

It says domain is not valid when trying to validate new domain extensions like .website etc...

```
    /*
 *      bool is_url(string $urladdr)
 *      check if a string is a syntactically valid url.
 */
function is_url($urladdr)
{ 
    $regexp = "^(https?://)";  // http:// 
    $regexp .= "?(([0-9a-z_!~*'().&=+$%-]+:)?[0-9a-z_!~*'().&=+$%-]+@)?";  // username:password@ 
    $regexp .= "(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}";  // IP- 199.194.52.184 
    $regexp .= "|";  // allows either IP or domain 
    $regexp .= "([0-9a-z_!~*'()-]+\.)*"; // tertiary domain(s)- www. 
    $regexp .= "([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]{0,61})?[0-9a-z]\."; // second level domain 
    $regexp .= "[a-z]{2,6})"; // first level domain- .com or .museum 
    $regexp .= "(:[0-9]{1,4})?"; // port number- :80 
    $regexp .= "((/?)|"; // a slash isn't required if there is no file name 
    $regexp .= "(/[0-9a-z_!~*'().;?:@&=+$,%#-]+)+/?)$"; // filename/queries/anchors 

    //qualified domain 
    if (eregi( $regexp, $urladdr ))
```

Comment: As a quick fix, you can change "[a-z]{2,6})" to "[a-z]{2,})". This will let .website through. Although this is still not a good solution because мова.бел would still not be validated.

Comment: I would start by using [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to split the URL into pieces then validate each piece by its own rules. And not by using [`ereg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php) because it is a deprecated function. Your code will stop working over the night (apparently without any reason) when your web hosting company decides to upgrade your site to PHP 7.

Comment: Removing the 6 does not work. Tried it.

Comment: Your regexp part for top level domains is broken. The currently existing longest TLD is .NORTHWESTERNMUTUAL, which is 18 characters (much longer than your limit of six). You're also throwing out all internationalized TLDs, of which more than a hundred currently exist.

Comment: Correction: longest TLD is XN--VERMGENSBERATUNG-PWB at 25 characters.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys! Good input.

Comment: So how do I fix it? If it is broken?

"Your regexp part for top level domains is broken. The currently existing longest TLD is .NORTHWESTERNMUTUAL, which is 18 characters (much longer than your limit of six). You're also throwing out all internationalized TLDs, of which more than a hundred currently exist. – Calle Dybedahl Mar 7 '17 at 11:30"